# Why is this MongoDB selector not working?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, database-schema

I have a SimpleSchema attached to Meteor.users with the following property:

```
tags: {
    type: [Object],
    label: "Tags",
    optional: true,   
    }
  },
  'tags.$.name' : {
    type: String,
  },
  'tags.$.correct' : {
    type: Number,
  },
  'tags.$.wrong' : {
    type: Number,
  },
```

And I have created a user with a single "Tag" object

```
"tags" : [
        {
            "name" : "History",
            "correct" : 0,
            "wrong" : 1
        },
    ]
```

But when I make the call

```
Meteor.users.findOne({
        'tags.$.name' : "History"
      });
```

It returns `undefined`. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thank you so much for helping. This has been stalling me for days. =\

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the fields option in your `findOne` statement.

This worked for me:

```
Meteor.users.findOne({
    'tags.name': "History"
}, {
    fields: {'tags.$': 1}
});
```

Comment: The solution was, like you recommended, to remove the $ from the selector. Plus, the fields option isn't necessary. And in my case, I didn't know what index the tag object would be at, but Mongo was smart enough to find the first result with a tag property that has an object with a name property of "History".......if that makes sense. Anyway, thank you!